# Long running queries on IPython?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter

I'm trying to execute a query that will take something like 30 seconds to return using pandas.read_sql(). It seems to work OK in sqlite terminal, but in the IPython interface I get nothing back. It works OK for other queries, so I'm assuming it's timing out.

How can I check if this is the case, and if so, increase the maximum wait time for IPython?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the query work in a regular Python script, outside IPython?

Comment: Showing the SQL command that works, and the python query that does not, would probably help.